# JUnit parameterized Tests Getting the parameter after the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, parameters, selenium, junit

So here's my dilemma. I have been using Selenium, TestNG, and iText to generate nice PDF reports from the results of an automated Test run, but I was told recently that they didn't want competing libraries TestNG vs. JUnit, and was told to start using JUnit instead.

I am running these JUnit tests with parameters, and am wondering is there a way to access the parameter after/during the test run? The parameters are Strings with browser names which is used to tell selenium which WebDriver to get, and it would be nice to know that a test passed/failed in a certain browser. JUnit seems to be very limited in the information you can access once a test run completes.

I have a class which extends `junit.framework.TestListener` which listens for the start/stop of each test, and here is where I can gather information about the test.

`currentTest` is of type `BaseTestResult` which is a class I wrote that simply stores test results in a list.

```
import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestListener;
import junit.framework.TestResult;
import utilities.reporting.BaseReporting;
import utilities.reporting.BaseTestResult;
import utilities.reporting.ResultsPerSuite;

public class BaseListener implements TestListener {

    private ResultsPerSuite resultsPerSuite;
    private BaseReporting baseReporter;
    private BaseTestResult currentSuite;
    private BaseTestResult currentTest;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private long suiteStartTime;
    private long suiteEndTime;

    public BaseListener() {
        baseReporter = new BaseReporting();
        resultsPerSuite = new ResultsPerSuite();
        currentTest = new BaseTestResult(null, null);
    }

    public void startSuite(Test suite) {
        suiteStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentSuite = new BaseTestResult(suite);
    }

    @Override
    public void startTest(Test arg0) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentTest = new BaseTestResult(arg0);     
    }

    @Override
    public void addError(Test arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        currentTest.addError(new BaseTestResult(arg0, arg1));

    }

    @Override
    public void addFailure(Test arg0, AssertionFailedError arg1) {
        currentTest.addFailed(new BaseTestResult(arg0, arg1));

    }

    @Override
    public void endTest(Test arg0) {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentTest.setRuntime(startTime - endTime);
        // If both empty, then test passed, so add to passed results.
        if (currentTest.getFailed().isEmpty()
                && currentTest.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
            resultsPerSuite.addPassed(currentTest);
        } else {
            resultsPerSuite.addFailed(currentTest);
        }
    }

    public void endSuite(TestResult testEventDriver) {
        suiteEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentSuite.setRuntime(suiteEndTime - suiteStartTime);
        resultsPerSuite.setSuite(currentSuite);

        baseReporter.printToConsole(resultsPerSuite);

    }

    /**
     * @return the allTestResults
     */
    public ResultsPerSuite getAllTestResults() {
        return resultsPerSuite;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't help you with your problem but I applaud your use of these tools.

Comment: Lol, thanks, a little encouragement is always appreciated. =P

Comment: This is wierd. Why are you using TestListener, which is JUnit 3, not RunListener, which is JUnit 4? Is there a reason you're using JUnit 3? This would mean you don't get access to all of the new stuff in JUnit 4.

Comment: I was in a rush so I used the first thing that came to mind that worked. I will look into RunListener though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to get it to do what you are looking for trivially from inside of the `TestListener` without creating your own `Runner`.  But you might be able to handle it with a [`TestRule`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html).

Since you appear to be using the listener to send the results to an external service, you might have better luck specifically by rigging in a [`TestWatcher`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) that communicates with your own listener. It would have access to the local class member variables and could report on them fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had to introduce a static variable and I am not a fan of static variables, but it works.